# A problem drawing arcs associated to angles

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations, arc

I need to draw arcs to denote angles inside an equilateral triangle.
To do this, I am using the arc function in tikz with the help of the calc package.
However, if I use an automatic solution which computes the degrees of the difference vectors between the vertexes, I get an undesired result (the black arc in the following example code).

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=8]
\coordinate (center) at (0, 0);
\coordinate (A) at (-0.5, 0);
\coordinate (B) at (0.5, 0);
\coordinate (C) at (0, {sqrt(3)/2});
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\coordinate (C1) at ($(C)!0.1!(A)$);
\coordinate (C2) at ($(C)!0.1!(B)$);
\draw
   let \p1 = ($(C1) - (C)$),
   \p2 = ($(C2) - (C)$),
   \n0 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)},            
   \n1 = {atan2(\x1, \y1)},  
   \n2 = {atan2(\x2, \y2)}   
 in (C) arc(\n1:\n2:\n0);
\path
    let     \p1 = ($(C1) - (C)$),
\p2 = ($(C2) - (C)$),
\n0 = {veclen(\x1, \y1)},
\n1 = {atan2(\x1, \y1)},
\n2 = {atan2(\x2, \y2)}
in node at  (C) {$\n1,\, \n2$};
\draw[red] (C1) arc(240:300:0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

If I display the values of the initial an final angles, they appear in pt which converted are like +60° and -60°.
These values are clearly wrong.
Vice versa, if I set the correct angles manually, then the arc is fine.
Nevertheless, I need to go through the "automatic" solution because I cannot manually compute the initial and final angles for more complex figures.
Can anybody tell me how to fix this problem?
Also, is there a way to display the initial and final angles in degrees rather than in points?
Thank you very much!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.  In particular, you seem to have certain Ti*k*Z libraries missing.

Comment: You can't give an angle in `pt`s as far as I know. That gives a length-type dimension. You know there is an `angle` library for drawing angles?

Comment: Why the huge scale?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you just want this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=8]
  \draw (-0.5,0) coordinate (A) -- (0.5,0) coordinate (B) -- (0,{sqrt(3)/2}) coordinate (C) -- cycle ($(C)!0.1!(A)$) coordinate (C1) ($(C)!0.1!(B)$) coordinate (C2);
  \draw
  let \p1 = ($(C1) - (C)$),
  \p2 = ($(C2) - (C)$),
  \n0 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)},
  \n1 = {atan2(\y1,\x1)},
  \n2 = {atan2(\y2,\x2)}
  in (C1) arc(\n1:\n2:\n0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: angle]

Note that `atan2` takes the `y` bit as its first argument - not the `x` - and that the `arc` should start from `(C1)` and not `(C)`.

Comment: If the problem is only how  designate angle by arc, than far more simpler is to use library `angles` and write `\pic {angle = A--C--B};` and omitted
all calculation of trigonometric functions.

Comment: @Zarko Yes. I mentioned that in comments. But I'm assuming from the question that that won't work in the author's real document because I take it the actual value is wanted back and I'm not sure how to get that from the `pic` in the `angle` library.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you decided to apply such a huge scale, instead of just using bigger measurements. Although this means loading an extra package, here's an example with `tkz-euclide`.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(-4,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(4,0){B}

\tkzDefTriangle[equilateral](A,B)
\tkzGetPoint{C}

\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)

\tkzMarkAngle[size=1cm](A,C,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```